# File Path is not absolute-selenium -AWS instance

Tags: selenium, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver

Functionality-Uploading a file.

When I run my code to upload a file in AWS instance, absolute path of the file which I get is like /home/ec2-user/project/src/.../filename. If the script tries to upload the file to the application under test with above path I get file path is not absolute error. Any suggestion on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried by using path.toAbsolutePath() method? this will give you absolute file path

Comment: Yes i have tried that...Since it is AWS i am getting this path "/home/ec2-user/..../file.txt".In local machine  i am getting the filepath perfectly.

Comment: Yes path.toAbsolutePath() gives me absolute path which is like "/home/ec2-user/..../file.txt" in case of AWS.